# List all documents (webparts) and sites using a certain solution in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007, uninstall, webpart

I would like to uninstall a Sharepoint application template (GroupBoard Workspace to be exact) but I want to make sure nothing currently relies on it.  I don't see any functions within stsadm that will tell me this information and I have even tried [SPM](http://spm.codeplex.com/) which would work, but with such a huge site it's tedious to go through every single web and page to see which features are in use.

Is there a way (probably with SQL using the id from `stsadm -o enumsolutions`) to list everything that relies on a template within a given solution, including webparts on custom pages?  If this is not possible, what is the best way to check dependencies prior to uninstalling a solution (especially since GBW is not the only one on my axe list.)

**Note:** I know that `stsadm -o deletesolution` will stop me from removing something that is in use, but I want to see all of the things that are using a given solution.